# вычисление интеграла, дискретная математика

Tags: c++, дискретная-математика

Мне необходимо вычислить интеграл. Область G, ограниченная окружностью x[SUP]2[/SUP]+y[SUP]2[/SUP]<=25, вписанная в квадрат D. Вычислить необходимо по формуле приведенной ниже. В условии дали ответ приблизительный 2pi(7-sqrt(24)), т.е 13,...?. Я написал код, взял рандомные x и y которые могут войти в прямоугольник D (т.е Ig), подставил формулу из под интеграла и вычислил сумму, а затем умножил все это на количество испытаний (1000) и площадь D, которая по идее по графику должна быть 4*25=100. Ответ не совсем сходится, выходит около 16, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так сделал.
Может это погрешность? Но тогда нормальная ли она?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(5234);
    int n = 1000000;
    int a = 5;
    float summa = 0;
    float area_d = 4 * pow(a, 2);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        float x = rand() % a;
        float y = rand() % a;
        if (pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) <= pow(a, 2)) {
            summa+=1/(sqrt(24+pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)));
        }
    }

    cout << "For n = " << n << " experimentov i  a = " << a << " polucili integral = " << (1. / n) * area_d * summa;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то двойной интеграл то по кругу, и там есть ещё и отрицательные кординаты.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, можно сказать, что в каком-то смысле это и погрешность. А вот если серьезно.. Вы же генерируете только целочисленные координаты `float x = rand() % a;` - о какой точности может идти речь? Ну и, как верно заметили в комментариях, у Вас должны быть координаты от -a до a. А еще, вот зачем Вы используете функцию `pow()` для банального возведения в квадрат? Это, как минимум, сильно ухудшает читаемость кода. А в худшем случае, если компилятор не умеет распознавать такие конструкции, то и к более медленным вычислениям.

Привожу немного подправленный код (ответ: 13.2103):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(5234);
    int n = 1000000;
    int a = 5;
    double summa = 0;
    double area_d = 4 * a * a;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        double x = 2.0 * rand()/RAND_MAX * a - a;   // от -a до a
        double y = 2.0 * rand()/RAND_MAX * a - a;   // от -a до a
        if (x*x + y*y <= a*a) {
            summa += 1.0/(sqrt(24+x*x+y*y));
        }
    }

    cout << "For n = " << n << "\nexperimentov i  a = " << a << "\npolucili integral = " << (1. / n) * area_d * summa << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```